# \multispan ->\omit \@multispan

Tags: tables, rotating

```
\begin{document}



\begin{sidewaystable}
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'

%\begin{tabular}{c|l|r|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\begin{tabular}{|p{15mm}|l|c|l|c|l|l|l|c|l|l|l|c|l|l|l|l|l|c|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}                    \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l}{k} &  \multicolumn{ 2}{|l|}{1} &                                      \multicolumn{4}{|l}{2} & \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{3} &                                                      \multicolumn{6}{|l}{4} &                                                      \multicolumn{6}{|l}{5} & $cdots$&255 \\  \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{$|b|=log_2(k)$} &  \multicolumn{ 2}{l|}{0} &                            \multicolumn{4}{l|}{1} & \multicolumn{ 4}{l|}{1.58} &                                                      \multicolumn{6}{|l|}{2} & \multicolumn{ 6}{c}{2.32} &$codts$ 7.99 \\            \hline
\cline{1-3}
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{$\vert{b}\rvert$}\ &\multicolumn{1}{c}{DE} &           \multicolumn{1}{|c}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{NA} &\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1}   & Possibility of bits & 0&1 & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1}  & Possibility of             bits & 0 & 1 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & Possibilty of bits & 0& 1 &10 &11       &\multicolumn{ 1}{c}{2} & Possibility of bits & 0 & 1 &10 &11 & & \\            \hline
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &             \multicolumn{ 1}{|c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{}&DE &10 &11 &                             \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & DE &  10 &11 & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{} & DE & 20 &             21&22&23&\multicolumn{ 1}{c}{}&DE&20&21&22 & 23 & $cdots$& \\\hline

    \end{tabular}  


\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Please suggest for merging table in landscape, because  some portion is missing. How can I set this issue. please suggest any one. I am new to latex.

Comment: Just check the below mentioned answer by Manuel!

Comment: You have, in two places, `\multicolumn` not preceded by `&`, where it should. However, such a table will never fit on a page: you should rething at how you want to present the data.

Comment: @egreg Now I see it: `\multicolumn{1}{r|}{21}\multicolumn{1}{r|}{22}` :)

Comment: Your edit seems to be a new question. If that's the case, then restore the old question and open a new question. By the way, is the original question solved? If yes, then please consider to accept the provided answer.

Comment: Your edit has broken the formatting of the code (I've fixed it). Please have a look into the [Help Center](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help) to find more information about [formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/formatting). See also [How you should get startet](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 2):

- Start with my template.
- Replace cell by cell with your content.
- Compile after every cell change.
- I think that your table is very wide -- does it fit on one page? :=)
- I counted 26 columns.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Caption of Table}
\label{tab:ExampleTable}
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|c|l|c|l|l|l|c|l|l|l|c|l|l|l|l|l|c|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 \\ 
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 \\ 
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

### Edit after Comment

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Caption of Table}
\label{tab:ExampleTable}
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|c|l|c|l|l|l|c|l|l|l|c|l|l|l|l|l|c|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 \\ 
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{1--2} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{3--6} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{7--10} & \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{11--16} & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your swift response, Dr. Manuel,I tried your suggestion but at third row, I have to  split all the cells into 2,4,4,6 and 6 columns.

Comment: @MadhuOruganti Have you tried "my" approach? I edited my answer. For further help, you should be more specific.

Comment: Yes I tried sir, I improved little bit  but I could not get the verticle lines in between the columns

Comment: @MadhuOruganti I do not understand what you mean. When you use `multicolumn` then you create a bigger cell where no *vertical lines* can be. Please edit your question and state clearly what you want and what you have tried. Use a very minimal example like my code (better less) but the code should be complete enough that people here can just compile it without further manual modification. Again, use "my" template and modify it a little bit. Then tell us what does not work and what you expect.

Comment: Ok. I am sorry to trouble you by giving such a big length code. I got the answer.

Comment: Ok. Please accept the answer by clicking on the arrow left of the answer if the problem is solved. Otherwise the question remains unanswered.